# Using Excel formula to SUM a number based on the letter infront

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a couple of cells with the following input:

V4   V5   V2   V3   V5   V7

I am trying to tell Excel to check the value infront, and see if its a V.
If this is TRUE, count the value next to it. This has to be done in a loop until it has passed through the range and summed all of the values.

This formula gets me nearly there.. but still no workable output.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:AO1,1)="V")*SUM(RIGHT(A1:AO1,1)))`

VBA is not a option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, use the **array formula**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:AO1,1)="V"),IFERROR(--RIGHT(A1:AO1,1),0))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

**EDIT#1:**

As mentioned in the Comment by *guitarthrower* , this will work if there is more than one digit following the **V:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:AO1,1)="V"),IFERROR(--RIGHT(A1:AO1,LEN(A1:AO1)-1),0))
```

**EDIT#2:**

If you are using a version of *Excel* before 2007, then use this array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:AO1,1)="V"),IF(ISERROR(--RIGHT(A1:AO1,LEN(A1:AO1)-1)),0,--RIGHT(A1:AO1,LEN(A1:AO1)-1)))
```

Comment: With a small change it will work if there is more than a 1 digit number after the letter (i.e. V25): `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A8,1)="V"),IFERROR(--RIGHT(A1:A8,LEN(A1:A8)-1),0))`

Comment: Works perfect in the latest Excel versions, Do you know any formula that is backward compatible with Excel 2003? user3616725 answer works in 2003 but only if all fields are filled. (some of them are empty)

Comment: @AlexanderH My answer is based on a suggestion by **Vijay A. Verma**

Comment: @AlexanderH  See my **EDIT#2** for versions of Excel prior to 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value next to the `V` is one digit long, you can use the following `IF` statement in excel to check if there is indeed a `V`, then assign the cell the value next to the `V`, or a zero.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1; 1)="V"; RIGHT(A1;1);0)
```

Afterwards, it's up to you to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fight excel, the obvious solution is to do:

```
  =IF(LEFT(A1,1) = "v", RIGHT(A1,1), 0)
```

on a column (you can hide it) and then sum it normally.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers all require a helper column, but your questions seems to suggest that is what you are trying to avoid.
try the formula below (abjust range as necessary):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A8,1)="V"),VALUE(RIGHT(A1:A8,1)))`

Please bear in mind that this will ONLY work if the number after the letter is always a single digit

Comment: It will also only work if all the cells in the range you list are filled in.